# NodeJS express sends wrong headers

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers

I have a server which alters response headers depending on the request headers and finally sends a file to the client. As in,

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  headers = {};
  if ("some_key" in req.headers) {
    headers["another_key"] = "some_value";
  }
  res.sendFile("public/some_index.html", {root: __dirname, "headers": headers});
});
```

If `"some_key"` is not in the request headers, then the response headers should not have `"another_key"` . However, the server returns the previous `"another_key"` value even if `"some_key"` is not present in the request headers this time.

I tried turning off the `etag` mechanism, using `res.set` to set the headers before sending the file as well as unsetting the response headers. In all cases, `"another_key"` was in the response even though it was not requested. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Which actual header are you refering to?

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify. The issue is response headers having `"another_key"` in the response even though they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue was the browser caching the response headers since the file is not updated (`HTTP 304`). (Although I think this should not be the case.)

As a solution, I added a dynamic value to the returned web page, e.g., page load count. This way, the cache is invalidated, and actual headers -- as intended by the server, are returned.

Answer (score -1):

Try prepending `const` to  `headers = {}`, like this:

```js
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  const headers = {};
  if ("some_key" in req.headers) {
    headers["another_key"] = "some_value";
  }
  res.sendFile("public/some_index.html", {root: __dirname, "headers": headers});
});
```

When you define a variable just like `variable = "some_value"` you are defining a global scope variable. So the next time your middleware is called it would be already defined and no matter if the code gets into the if block, `headers` will contain the keys assigned in the previous call.

Comment: I tried `let` and `const` headers, neither worked.